# Can the count function be used for strings within a function?

Tags: python, list, function, random, count

I am trying to make a function that randomly selects from two options nine times and returns the number of times each option was chosen. However, each time I try to run the code, the count function returns [None].

```
 import random
topic=["Insomnia","REM Sleep Disorder"]
def func():
  print(random.choice(topic))
  print(random.choice(topic))
  print(random.choice(topic))
  print(random.choice(topic))
  print(random.choice(topic))
  print(random.choice(topic))
  print(random.choice(topic))
  print(random.choice(topic))
  print(random.choice(topic))


  
x=[func()]
y=x.count("Insomnia")
print(x)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: printing things in `func()` doesn't do anything to `x`. You need to follow a tutorial on functions. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials, because it's meant for answers to _specific_ questions, not to give you a broad understanding of a bunch of related concepts.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be a comment, but I think it's too long ...

You're not setting anything in `func` - you're only printing out the information. If you want to use output information from a function you have to return it.

```
def func() 
    return [ random.choice(topic) for _ in range(9) ]
```

SHould return a list of 9 random choices for you though you could use the list comprehension directly and avoid the function here.

Comment: func() will already return a list, not need to use x=[func()], use x=func()

Comment: No, I said that would return a list

Comment: Yes, i know. I meant his implementation has a little mistake, as he packs your return in another list ;)